# vuejs yup validate disable type checking

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

i have a problem i am using metronic theme i am using vue js 3 composition api with yup validate

yup validate gives a type error in some cases and I can control this error with typeError(), but what I want is to disable this type checking completely, how can I do this?

thank you for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.